# Using jQuery FileReader to get width and height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, filereader

I'm using jQuery to show an image in a div (#image-preview) when an image is selected, and I can't figure out how to get the width and the height of the image; I'm using "this.width" and "this.height".

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $('input#photo').on('change', function() {
                    var files = !!this.files ? this.files : [];
                    if (!files.length || !window.FileReader) return; // no file selected, or no FileReader support
                    if (/^image/.test(files[0].type)) {  // only image file
                        var reader = new FileReader();   // instance of the FileReader
                        reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);  // read the local file
                        reader.onloadend = function() {  
                            $('div#image-preview').css('display', 'inline-block');
                            $('div#image-preview').css('background-image', 'url(' + this.result + ')'); // set image data as background of div
                            $('div#image-preview').css('width', this.width); // doesn't work??
                            $('div#image-preview').css('height', this.height); // doesn't work??
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

`FileReader` has not the properties width and height. You can use `Image` instead like following. Hope this will help you.

```js
$('input#photo').on('change', function () {
      var files = !!this.files ? this.files : [], _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
      if (!files.length) return;

      if (/^image/.test(files[0].type)) { 
         var img = new Image();
         img.onload = function () {
              $('div#image-preview').css('display', 'inline-block');
              $('div#image-preview').css('background-image', 'url(' + this.src + ')');
              $('div#image-preview').css('width', this.width);
              $('div#image-preview').css('height', this.height);
         };
         img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);
      }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="photo"/>
<div id="image-preview"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to save to a variables the width and height of the photo using this, right in the beginning of the first function, then, use those variables in the second function.. It's a scope issue.